Details of Jewish land acquisition in Egypt
At the end of the famine, there were only three types of landowners. Pharaoh, priests, and the Israelites. All the peasants were serfs to Pharaoh and paid 20%.
Then the Israelites start buying land, probably from Pharaoh because he had more than he needed.

27And Israel dwelt in the land of Egypt in the land of Goshen, and they acquired property in it, and they were prolific and multiplied greatly.

What happened to the peasants on the land? Were they still held to the 20% or did the Israelites raise the rents or did they just expell the peasants?

Where is this translation from? The Hebrew וַיֵּאָחֲז֣וּ בָ֔הּ doesn't say "they acquired property" (at least, not literally)

The chabad tanach website. The translation probably follows Rashi.
